# (AD) object equality in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The following seems quite weird to me:

```
$user1 = Get-ADUser sameuser
$user2 = Get-ADUser sameuser
$user1 -eq $user2                # -> false
# the same for groups:
$group1 = Get-ADGroup samegroup
$group2 = Get-ADGroup samegroup
$group1 -eq $group2              # -> false
```

Actually it seems that Powershell users can be happy that `1 -eq 1` is true. Also:

```
"1" -eq 1           # -> true
@("1") -contains 1  # -> true
```

But:

```
$h1 = @{bla = 1}
$h2 = @{bla = 1}
$h1 -eq $h2                          # -> false
$h1.GetHashCode(), $h2.GetHashCode() # -> 60847006, 5156994
# the above return values of course vary
$a1 = @(1;2;3)
$a2 = @(1;2;3)
$a1.GetHashCode(), $a2.GetHashCode() # -> 52954848, 34157931
# surprise, surprise:
$a1 -eq $a2           # no return value at all? (tested with versions 4.0 and 5.1)
($a1 -eq $a2).GetType()              # or an Array?
($a1 -eq $a2).count                  # -> 0
```

Aside from these funny behaviors what really feels frustrating is that I cannot simply do it this way:

```
$ones      = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership one
$seconds   = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership second
$excl_ones = $ones | ? { $_ -notin $seconds }
```

But have to do something like this:

```
$second_nms = $seconds | % name
$excl_ones = $ones | ? { $_.name -notin $second_nms }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should always compare AD objects on their `objectGUID` value

Comment: Your `$a1 -eq $a2` has no return value, because using an operator with an array on the left acts as a filter against the contents of the array. It's not asking if array 1 equals array 2, it's asking for all the items in $a1 which equal $a2.  Compare `@(1,2,1,2) -eq 2`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler This is actually a nice feature I was not aware of. But one could of course argue consistency looks different. `@(1,2,1,2) -eq 2 -> @(2,2)` while `2 -eq @(1,2,1,2) -> false`.

Comment: @TNT I'd say the design makes more sense for "all values less than 10": `@(1,4,12,16) -lt 10` rather than "all values that are 2", and more so for text, all lines which match a regex: `@("line1", "line2", "line3") -match 'e[13]'` then you don't expect the reverse pattern "ten is greater than an array of numbers" or `'e[13]' -match @("line1", "line2", "line3")` to make as much sense.

Answer (score 8):

To understand some of the oddities your seeing we have to take a step back and consider the bigger picture, namely the framework PowerShell is built on top of: .NET!

## Object Equality in .NET

`$user1 -eq $user2` fails because `$user1` and `$user2` are *two different objects* - although they may both *represent* the same object in Active Directory.

When it comes to object equality in .NET, you'll need to distinguished between *value equality* and *reference equality*.

Two variables of a *value type*, like `[int]` for example, are considered equal if their underlying value is the same:

```
$a = 1
$b = 1
$a.Equals($b) # $true
```

Two variables of a *reference type* - anything that's not a value type - are usually only considered equal if they have the same *identity* - that is, they refer to the same object in memory:

```
$a = New-Object object
$b = New-Object object
$a.Equals($b) # $false
```

For all we know, `$a` and `$b` are exactly the same, but they refer to two distinct `[object]` instances in memory.

A type definition can override `GetHashCode()` (the function used to determine an object's *identity*) and `Equals()` (the function used to determine equality between two objects), so you may find that some reference types seem to act as value types when comparing them - `[string]` being a prime example:

```
$a = "test"
$b = "test"
$a.Equals($b)
```

The `ADEntity` class (the base type for all output objects in the ActiveDirectory module) doesn't attempt something like this, which is why you see the results you do.

## Collection filtering in PowerShell

The above doesn't quite explain another weird thing you raised, namely this:

```
$a1 = @(1;2;3)
$a2 = @(1;2;3)
$a1 -eq $a2 # NOTHING! WHAT'S GOING ON HERE?
```

To understand what's going on here, you need to study comparison operator behavior in PowerShell itself!

All the comparison operators (`-eq`, `-ne`, `-gt`, `-like`, `-match` etc.) support two different modes depending on the left-hand side argument: *scalar* and *filtering*.

#### Scalar comparison

In scalar mode, a comparison operator takes a single object as its left-hand operand, a value expression as its right-hand operand and returns a boolean result: `$true` or `$false`.

#### Filtering using comparison operators

In filtering mode, a comparison operator takes a *collection* (an array or a list) as its left-hand operand, a value expression as its right-hand operand (just like before) and returns *all the individual members of the left-hand collection that satisfy the comparison*.

To see this in action, try the following:

```
$names  = "James","Jane","John"
$prefix = "Ja"

$names -like "$prefix*"
```

You'll see that the `-like` operations returns two strings - `James` and `Jane`.

If we apply this newfound knowledge to your example

```
@(1;2;3) - eq @(1;2;3)
```

it becomes obvious why nothing is returned - the left hand operand is clearly an array, and neither of the ensuing comparisons (`1 -eq @(1;2;3)`, `2 -eq @(1;2;3)` etc.) will return `$true`

---

Now on to the practical part of your problem. Active Directory is designed in a way so that each object in the directory has a unique identifier you can use to figure out the identity of it - the `objectGUID` value. A `GUID` in .NET happens to be a value type, so you can safely use it as a basis for you comparison:

```
$ones      = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership one
$seconds   = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership second
$excl_ones = $ones | ? { $_.objectGUID -notin $seconds.objectGUID }
```

For security principals (groups, users, computers etc.), another unique identifier that's safe to use is the `objectSID` - security identifiers are always unique.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, that's really amazing (I mean the practical part)! I don't fully get it yet but at a first glance this - I mean the array property that *contains* an array of the respective properties of the array's contents - seems for example more elegant than the model_ids method of Ruby on Rails' ActiveRecord classes. This will make me sleep better tonight.`('h','u','r','r','a' | % { @{yes = $_} }).yes`

Comment: Awesome explanation @Mathias.

Comment: I've edited the title and replaced *identity* with *equality* because, as you name it correctly, that is what I'm actually talking about.

Comment: @TNT I updated the answer with a bit about the `@(1;2;3) -eq @(1;2;3)` mystery